# Rewriting the product of expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable. For given functions $f$ and $g$, can we rewrite $E[f(X)]\cdot E[g(X)]$ as $E[h(X)]+\frac{1}{2}(E[i(X)])^2$ for some functions $h$ and $i$?

I tried $E[f(X)]\cdot E[g(X)]=E[f(X)\cdot g(X)]-E[(f(X)-E[f(X)])\cdot (g(X)-E[g(X)])]$ but got stucked.

Edit: Let me be more precise. For given $f$ and $g$, I am looking for $h$ and $i$ such that $E[f(X)]\cdot E[g(X)]=E[h(X)]+\frac{1}{2}(E[i(X)])^2$ for any random variable $X$.

Comment: I think you should include some motivation because there is a pretty obvious trivial solution to pick $h$ and $i$ as appropriate constant functions.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thanks for your comments. I realized that here $X$ should not be a given random variable. In other words, no matter what $X$ is, the rewriting should be true. Then I think constant functions do not work.